# Make data frame out of list

Tags: r

My problem is really simple: I have a dataframe with 3 columns

```
       > head(subset_only_aster)
                       compound                                     contrast sign_level
2  10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14-MeC30  Precocene.undeveloped - Acetone.undeveloped  *         
7  10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14-MeC30    Precocene.developed - Acetone.undeveloped **
```

Of which I want to make a data frame where 'compound' should be the row names (there are 65 compounds all together), the 'contrasts' (which is a variable with 6 levels) should be the columns (6 columns) and the variable 'sign_level' should be the data in the data frame.

Don't know where to begin, can't find the answer on the web neither. Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you do `dput(your_dataframe)` and paste the result to make it easier to work with it?

Comment: Maybe this is a job for `reshape` with parameter `direction="wide"`.

Comment: @KarstenW. I think you are right or for `melt` and `dcast` in `reshape2`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution:

```
dat <- expand.grid(compounds=letters[1:3], contrast=LETTERS[5:10])
dat[, "sgn"] <- sample(c("*", "**", "***"), nrow(dat), replace=TRUE)
reshape(dat, direction="wide", idvar="compounds", timevar="contrast")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spread-function in tidyr:

```
DF<-data.frame(compound=rep(LETTERS[1:2],2),
    contrast=c(rep(letters[1],2),rep(letters[2],2)),
           signlevel=1:4)
```

[image]

```
library(tidyr)
DF2<-tidyr::spread(DF,contrast,signlevel)
```

[image]